# Change images on hover in product list page

Tags: magento-2.1, product, attributes, product-attribute, product-list

I need to add the image change on hover functionality into the product list page in *Magento 2*.

When user is in product list page, when he/she hovers mouse over the displayed product, it should show change of image/another image on mouse click and revert back to originally displayed image when user moves mouse pointer away. I added changed image as a custom product attribute as follows.

I added a custom product attribute which has the *Media Image* in *Catalog Input Type for Store Owner* option. Then I gave attribute code as **hover_image**. I Set *Add to Column Options* and *Use in Filter Options* to "No".

Then I added my new attribute into attribute set -> *default*.
Moved my attribute into *images* group. Then I can upload image from backend ( Products->Catalog ) and choose image role as *hover_image*.

How can I check if certain product has image for **hover_image** and if that product has one, How can I add the hover effect on product list page?

I tried looping through products in list.phtml but I failed. can anyone just give me a hand? even a pointer to right direction would be helpful. Also it's okay even if you know a way for using direct usage of object manager.

Answer (score 3):

In `list.phtml` use `$productImageHover = $block->getImage($_product, 'hover_image');`, to get the hover image and add a class for hidden, and on `.product-item:hover` display the image, also the image width and height should be the same as the main image for the listing `category_page_grid/category_page_list` depending on your situation, don't forget to hide the "non-hover" image on hover